# Change html select option:disable text color on Mac Chrome and Safari

Tags: css

I am trying to change select option:disable text color, it on Windows Chrome but nothing happen for Mac Chrome and Safari.

so the question is, how can I change select option:disable text color on Mac Chrome and Safari?

```
# html 
<select id="product-size">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="">S</option>
    <option value="" disabled="">M</option>
    <option value="">L</option>
    <option value="">XL</option>
</select>

# CSS
select option:disabled{
    color: red;
}
```

many thanks

Comment: did you use `-webkit-color`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50374) in chrome.

No style is applied in the `option` of `select` in `Mac`

Answer (score 0):

Chrome, Firefox and Safari, on Mac :
this works for me (only default disabled option is red)

```
  <select class="myDefaultClass c-red" onchange="this.className='myDefaultClass'">
      <option value="" disabled="disabled">Choose something</option>
      <option value="one">1</option>
      <option value="two">2</option>
      <option value="more">+2</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Onthemail: What css you used to change the disable option color. Thanks